# How to use value of inherited class member, when upcasting to base class

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, c++17

I have a problem with displaying the content of inherited class members, when up casting to the base class. Currently, the result displayed is **4**, how can I achieve **2**?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>

class A {
public:
  A() = default;  
  std::vector<int> v = {3, 4, 5};
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() { v = {1, 2, 3}; }
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
};

int main() {
   std::vector<std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<A>, int>> v = {
        std::make_tuple<std::shared_ptr<A>, int>(std::make_shared<B>(), 5) 
    };

    std::shared_ptr<A> obj;
    std::tie(obj, std::ignore) = v[0];
    std::cout << obj->v[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why? You should not access members of `B` via a pointer to `A`. It is a bit odd that both `A` and `B` have a member with the same name. You know that in `B` both `v`s are present? Is it possible that you rather want `B` to initialize `A`s `v` with `{1,2,3}` ?

Comment: Do you want this: https://godbolt.org/z/KfC2KN ?

Comment: Actually, just for learning purposes. I don't know if I find this useful or this is a good idea ;) Yes, you solved my problem. Also I was able to write this now: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e76166a0609a0a17

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to use value of inherited class member, when upcasting to base class

By using runtime polymorphism. Write a virtual function.

In this case, a virtual overloaded subscript operator might be appropriate:

```
struct A {
    virtual int& operator[](std::size_t index) = 0;
};

struct B : A {
    int& operator[](std::size_t index) override {
        return v[index];
    }

    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
};
```

Usage:

```
std::cout << obj[1] << std::endl;
```

Comment: um, didnt consider that possibility. +1

Answer (score 3):

Having member of same type and name in the base and the derived is not wrong, but I have the feeling that you are not aware of the consequences. A `B` object has two members called `v`. For illustration consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { int x = 3; };    
struct B : A { int x = 5; };

int main() {
    B b;
    std::cout << b.x;
    std::cout << b.A::x;
}
```

Output is: `53`

If you want `B` to initialize the member `v` with `{1,2,3}` then you can do two things: Provide a constructor for `A` that initializes the member, and call that constructor in `B`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
  A() = default;  
  A(std::vector<int> v) : v(v) {}
  std::vector<int> v = {3, 4, 5};
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() : A({1,2,3}) {}
};

int main() {
    B b;
    std::cout << b.v[0];
}
```

Output: `1`

To answer your question literally:

> How to use value of inherited class member, when upcasting to base class

Usually you should not access members of a derived class directly when you have a pointer to base class. It is possible via a `dynamic_cast` but casts should be avoided when possible. Instead the base class should provide the necessary interface.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that you have two different fields A::v and B::v. And when accessing v from outside it will reach the field in the derived class (note, these two Fields has nothing to do with eachother - they can be different types for instance.)

To actually reach the base v field, you would do

```
obj->A::v[1];
```

However, be aware if this is actually what you want. Without knowing more, it is hard to say for certain, but it looks like flawed design.